# Force update POD with dependency of another pod

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have POD 'FolioReaderKit' which has dependencies of another pods such as Realm RealmSwift
When I install the pod I get:

```
FolioReaderKit: 1.4.0
- Realm 3.13.1
- RealmSwift 3.13.1
```

The version of FolioReaderKit is the latest however the Realm version is way too old there is 3.19.1 and I need to update it.

In the pod file the platform is set to ios 12.1 and after making "pod update" nothing happens. If I add manually RealmSwift ~> 3.19.1 it gives error that FolioReaderKit depends on this library RealmSwift 3.13.1

How to update Realm and RealmSwift to the latest version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, using the `FolioReaderKit 1.4.0` pod, you can't.

On the [1.4.0 release podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/2/c/a/FolioReaderKit/1.4.0/FolioReaderKit.podspec.json), it depends explicitly on RealmSwift 3.13.1:

```
"RealmSwift": [
  "3.13.1"
]
```

On the other hand, `RealmSwift 3.13.1` [depends](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/9/4/5/RealmSwift/3.13.1/RealmSwift.podspec.json) on the same version of Realm:

```
"dependencies": {
  "Realm": [
    "= 3.13.1"
  ]
}
```

So you can't just manually update the versions.

The only way you can update this is creating a local copy of `FolioReaderKit` and manually modifying its `podspec` file, but it probably has some reason to fix the pod dependency version, so it is likely to crash.